# java.lang.VerifyError thrown when creating a method using JavaAssist

Tags: java, code-generation, javassist, verifyerror

I am trying to use JavaAssist version 3.12.1.GA to do some runtime code generation of a Pojo implementing an interface using Java 8. I ran into an error when trying to create a method that has a return type of Object.

The error:

`Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: person, method: getColumnByIndex signature: (I)Ljava/lang/Object;) Wrong return type in function`

gets thrown when adding the `getColumnByIndex` method.

Here is the full example class:

```
public class Example {

    public interface Domain {
        public int getIdentifier();
        public Object getColumnByIndex(int i);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        final ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        final CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("Person");
        cc.addInterface(resolveCtClass(Domain.class));

        final CtField idField = new CtField(CtClass.intType, "id", cc);
        final CtMethod idGetter = CtNewMethod.getter("getId", idField);
        final CtMethod idSetter = CtNewMethod.setter("setId", idField);
        cc.addField(idField);
        cc.addMethod(idGetter);
        cc.addMethod(idSetter);

        final CtField firstNameField = new CtField(resolveCtClass(String.class), "firstName", cc);
        final CtMethod firstNameGetter = CtNewMethod.getter("getFirstName", firstNameField);
        final CtMethod firstNameSetter = CtNewMethod.setter("setFirstName", firstNameField);
        cc.addField(firstNameField);
        cc.addMethod(firstNameSetter);
        cc.addMethod(firstNameGetter);

        final CtMethod getIdentifier = CtNewMethod.make("public int getIdentifier () { return id; }", cc);
        cc.addMethod(getIdentifier);            

        final CtMethod getColumnByIndex = CtNewMethod.make(
                    "public Object getColumnByIndex(int i) {"
                    +   "switch (i) {"
                    +       "case 0:"
                    +           "return id;"
                    +       "case 1:"
                    +           "return firstName;"
                    +       "default: "
                    +           "throw new IllegalArgumentException(\"Tried getting column index i, but this column index does not exist\");"
                    +   "}"
                    + "}", cc);
        cc.addMethod(getColumnByIndex);
        final Class<?> dynamicClass = cc.toClass();

        final Domain domainImpl = (Domain) dynamicClass.newInstance();
        System.out.println(domainImpl.getIdentifier());
        System.out.println(domainImpl.getColumnByIndex(0));
    }

    private static CtClass resolveCtClass(final Class<?> clazz) throws NotFoundException {
        final ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        return pool.get(clazz.getName());
    }
```

**How can I resolve the java.lang.VeryifyError?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `id` field of type `int` is not automatically boxed into `Integer`, so you either do it by hand:

```
switch (i) {
  case 0: return Integer.valueOf(id);
  case 1: return firstName;
  default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
}
```

or you convert everything to `Integer`, including the return type of `Domain.getIdentifier()`. Primitive types in Java are not `Object`'s! Wrapper types exist to fake a single root hierarchy in the JVM, and the compiler silently inserts calls like `Integer.valueOf(int)` and `Integer.intValue()` when appropriate, but sometimes the abstraction leaks up to the user.

Since the code you are writing seems a database access thing, I'd prefer the second option so that everything can be nullable - otherwise to represent a record yet-to-be-inserted you'd have to rely on some canary value like zero, -1 or whatever.

<sup>The runnable [gist](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/410e6e77d08219f7054b9fbccce3c0cf)</sup>

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the explanation and the writen code in gist. The code is indeed a database thingy so I will follow your recommendation with regard to the wrapping. I did actually have trouble mapping a column from a database (to a flat file) that was of type integer. When the integer was empty it was represented by a 0 instead of just an empty field.